# Analysis of table to make compressing model

Tags: text-mining, orange

I have a table with hundred of entries in this style:

`//HEADER//CODE1//decimals_here//CODE4//decimals_here//CODE3//decimals_here//CODE5//decimals_here//ENDING//`

I want to make a **simple text compressor** that works for only **1 entry at each time**. Can someone give me a kickstart hint to start playing in Orange?

1. Where do I split the text for better analysis? Can I find that also in Orange?
2. How can I get the most repeated/common segments and their occurrence?

Thanks

Comment: See [Preprocess Text widget](https://orangedatamining.com/widget-catalog/text-mining/preprocesstext/) > Tokenization, then [Bag of Words](https://orangedatamining.com/widget-catalog/text-mining/bagofwords-widget/) to get term frequency. I found the widgets here: https://orangedatamining.com/widget-catalog

Comment: Nice thanks! I wonder if there is something similar to find 2 words in sequence that are common in a similar way